# Redis: Lua script to return every other nth element of a sorted set

Tags: lua, redis

I am trying to put together a lua script to be called from Redis (via an EVAL call) in order to return every other nth element of a sorted set (nth being the rank in the set, not the score).

There are very few online examples of Lua scripts that can be used to build upon, would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local function copyNOtherElements(table, interval, startpos)

local elemno = 1
local rettab = {}

for k, v in ipairs(table) do
   if k >= startpos and (k - startpos) % interval == 0 then
      rettab[elemno] = v
      elemno = elemno + 1
   end
end

return rettab

end
```

Sorry  about formatting,  typing on a phone.  that's assuming the table is a 1  based array

Comment: Thanks very much, looking at plugging it into the Redis call and will report back if I encounter any Redis specific issues. Looks good to me (the table is indeed a 1 based array).

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, adding Redis into the previous answer, and a bit more efficient code to iterate the Nth elements:

```
local function zrange_pick(zset_key, step, start, stop)
    -- The next four lines can be removed along with the start/stop params if not needed as in OP Q.
    if start == nil than
        start = 0
    if end == nil than
        end = -1

    local set_by_score = redis.call('ZRANGE', zset_key, start, end)
    local result = {}
    for n = 1, #set_by_score, step do
        table.insert(result, set_by_score[n])
    end
    return result
end
```